# Stop resizing beyond screen resolution range (JavaFX)

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

I'm developing a JavaFX application (with Java version 8u51) and I made it `resizable` but the default behavior that I have right now is not the desired one. The problem is that I am able to `resize` it beyond the screen resolution range. In other words, I can make the `Stage` bigger than my screen. Is there a way to limit the `resize` to the current monitor resolution? I have to mention that I need this to work on any resolution and any screen size.

Comment: Such limitations are the job of the desktop environment.  Why do you feel you need to do this?  No other application does this.

Comment: @VGR Well, I can resize my app to max width, than move it a bit to the left and resize again and make it bigger and so on...I would like to limit that possibility.

Comment: I understand, but why do you care?  If a user has some reason for making a window larger than the screen, and the desktop allows it, why should your application care more than any other application does?

Comment: @VGR Actually I just checked and for example Microsoft applications do limit the size. As I just saw, applications are limited to the size of all monitors (2 monitors next to each other at 1920x1080 results in the maximum size of 3840x1080)

Comment: @Robert If I am not mistaken you just want to connect two monitors, and make app (Stage) size double in width. Am I right?

Comment: @TirrNs What I want is to limit the app dimensions so the user doesn't resize the stage bigger than the actual available pixels.

Comment: You’re correct.  Windows already does not allow a window to be resized larger than the screen.  My JavaFX applications are already prevented from doing so—even though I have not set any maximum size on my Stage.  The desktop environment already enforces this limitation.  No code is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Screen` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) enables you to find the different physical screens available at runtime, their [bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getBounds--) (which includes their sizes), and resolution in [dots per inch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html#getDpi--). Then you can set the maximum [width](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setMaxWidth-double-) and [height](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setMaxHeight-double-) on your stage accordingly.

(It's not really clear to me exactly what you mean by "resize it beyond the screen resolution range", but this should give you the API to implement what you are trying to do.)

Comment: I tried "instance.setMaxWidth(Screen.getMainScreen().getWidth());" but I'm still able to resize it to more than 1920 (that's my screen)

Comment: @Robert There is no such method in the `Screen` class.

Comment: Yeah, I think I was using the wrong package. I found the right one with bounds. I'm trying to implement a resize listener now.

Comment: @Robert I don't think you need a resize listener.

Comment: instance.setMaxHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxY());
instance.setMaxWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxX());
didn't help...

Comment: Why are you using `getMaxX()` and `getMaxY()`? Using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` works fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

> Yes, but what if the user wants to resize it again...smaller, this action should be permitted.

In this case you need to set actual size of the stage when the app launched and maximum allowed resizable size.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane());
    stage.setScene(scene);

    Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
    stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
    stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
    stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
    stage.setMaxWidth(bounds.getWidth() * 2);
    stage.show();
}
```

In here:

```
stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
stage.setMaxWidth(bounds.getWidth() * 2);
```

you may set the size you want. You may even set minimum size of the stage by `stage.setMinWidth()` and/or `stage.setMinHeight()`.

Comment: But wouldn't this just block the resize? I want the user to be able to resize the stage, but not bigger than the screen.

Comment: Yes, it blocks. So, you allow the user resizing stage until it is not bigger than some special size, right?

Comment: Yes, but what if the user wants to resize it again...smaller, this action should be permitted.

Comment: In this case you should just set `primaryStage.setMaxWidth(3840);`. How about dragging, closing or minimizing stage?